# Couchbase C SDK LCB_ERR_TIMEOUT (201) Error issue

Tags: c, sdk, nosql, couchbase

I was originally having issues with getting authentication errors when trying to do update a bucket. I then updated the server to a more up to date Couchbase server. Now I keep getting timeout errors, specifically LCB_ERR_TIMEOUT (201) when trying to do upsert into the bucket. Is there a possible issue in network or am I doing something wrong in code?

Code:

```
#define __STDC_FORMAT_MACROS
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "libcouchbase/couchbase.h"

static void open_callback(lcb_INSTANCE* instance, lcb_STATUS rc)
{
    printf("Open bucket: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open bucket: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

static void store_callback(lcb_INSTANCE* instance, int cbtype, const lcb_RESPSTORE* resp)
{
    const char* key;
    size_t nkey;
    uint64_t cas;
    lcb_respstore_key(resp, &key, &nkey);
    lcb_respstore_cas(resp, &cas);
    printf("Storage callback\n");
    printf("Status: %s, Key: %.*s, CAS: %" PRIx64 "\n",
           lcb_strerror_short(lcb_respstore_status(resp)), (int)nkey, key, cas);

}

int main()
{
    const char* connection_string = "couchbase://localhost";
    const char* username = "username";
    const char* password = "password";
    const char* bucket = "bucket-name";

    //connection credentials 
    lcb_CREATEOPTS* create_options = NULL;
    lcb_createopts_create(&create_options, LCB_TYPE_CLUSTER);
    lcb_createopts_connstr(create_options, connection_string, strlen(connection_string));
    lcb_createopts_credentials(create_options, username, strlen(username), password, strlen(password));

    //create an instance using default values
    lcb_INSTANCE* instance;
    lcb_STATUS rc = lcb_create(&instance, NULL); //rc is return code that needs to be checked
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create instance: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //initializes with credentials
    rc = lcb_create(&instance, create_options);
    rc = lcb_createopts_destroy(create_options);

    //schedule intial connection to server
    rc = lcb_connect(instance);
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to schedule connection object: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    rc = lcb_wait(instance, LCB_WAIT_DEFAULT);
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to wait for connection: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    rc = lcb_get_bootstrap_status(instance);
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to bootstrap cluster connection: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // associate instance with a bucket
    lcb_set_open_callback(instance, open_callback);
    rc = lcb_open(instance, bucket, strlen(bucket));
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to schedule open bucket operation: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    rc = lcb_wait(instance, LCB_WAIT_DEFAULT);
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to wait for open bucket operation: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    lcb_install_callback(instance, LCB_CALLBACK_STORE, (lcb_RESPCALLBACK)store_callback);

    lcb_CMDSTORE* cmd;
    const char* key = "test-doc";
    const char* value = "{\"Name\": \"name\"}";
    rc = lcb_cmdstore_create(&cmd, LCB_STORE_UPSERT); //create upsert command
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create upsert command: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    rc = lcb_cmdstore_key(cmd, key, strlen(key)); //assign key for upsert command
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to assign key for upsert: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    rc = lcb_cmdstore_value(cmd, value, strlen(value)); //assign value for upsert command
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to assign value for upsert: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    rc = lcb_store(instance, NULL, cmd); //schedule upsert command
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to schedule upsert command: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    rc = lcb_cmdstore_destroy(cmd); //destroy upsert command
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to wait for upsert to complete: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    rc = lcb_wait(instance, LCB_WAIT_DEFAULT); //wait for scheduled operations to finish
    if (rc != LCB_SUCCESS) {
        lcb_destroy(instance);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to wait for upsert to complete: %s\n", lcb_strerror_short(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Open bucket: LCB_SUCCESS (0)
Storage callback
Status: LCB_ERR_TIMEOUT (201), Key: Test, CAS: 0
```

Here is the log: https://paste.centos.org/view/3cb44d50

Comment: did you find any resolution for this error? I need help on the same for node js sdk.

Comment: Did you find any resolution for this error ?